# Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes - Serilog.AspNetCore

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, nuget, visual-studio-2017, serilog

I have an asp.net Core project and I'm trying to add a logger to it.
I choose SeriLog which I used in other projects.

But when I'm trying to add the "**Serilog.AspNetCore**" package version 2.0.0 I'm getting"

> Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'BackEnd'.

My csproj contain the following settings:

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
   <DockerComposeProjectPath>..\..\docker-compose.dcproj</DockerComposeProjectPath>
   <AssemblyName>BackEnd</AssemblyName>
  <RootNamespace>BackEnd</RootNamespace>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Allready tried to clear all nuget cache, rebuilding, restart VS

Running on Win10, Visual Studio 2017 15.3.0

Is there a log that can give me more details why I'm getting this error?
Any suggestions how to fix it?

***Update - the detailed build log** (Thanks @Leo-MSFT for that):

> ...
>
> Checking compatibility for System.Security.Cryptography.Csp 4.3.0 with .NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0.
>
> Checking compatibility for runtime.osx.10.10-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.Apple 4.3.0 with .NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0.
>
> All packages and projects are compatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0.
>
> Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection from 2.0.0 to 1.1.1. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.
>
> BackEnd (>= 1.0.0) -> Serilog.AspNetCore (>= 2.0.0) -> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection (>= 2.0.0)
>
> BackEnd (>= 1.0.0) -> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection (>= 1.1.1)
>
> Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'BackEnd'.
>
> Time Elapsed: 00:00:01.4928161
>
> ========== Finished ==========

Yep it seems that it's related to "**Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection**"

Comment: try manually add `<PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0"/>` into your .csproj and then do `dotnet restore`

Comment: What is the detailed installation log on the output window? You can change the MSBuild output verbosity to Detailed or Diagnostic, Tools->Options->Build and Run->MSBuild project build output verbosity.

Comment: I tried it also, but I'm getting: "Restoring NuGet packages...
NuGet package restore failed."

Comment: @Leo-MSFT thanks for the input, I added the build log.. seems that it's related to "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" mismatch version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved by updating all my existence Nuget packages to the latest version available.
Including those 5 packages:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="2.0.0" />
```

The problem was the version of **"Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection"** but I update all of them.

Comment: thanks for sharing your solution here, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues.

Comment: Had to wait 2 days in order todo so.. I updated it now, thanks