# Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for "<project name>" for a brand new CORE empty project

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core

Using VS 2017, v15.1, Win 7, have many projects running no problem. I simply

- New, Project, Web C#, .NET Core Web App (.NET Core)
- ASP.NET Core 1.1 Templates
- F5, see "Hello World" in IE
- Tool, NuGet, Browse, try to add Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles, Install got "Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes".

Maybe something is not up to date? Nuget again, it prompts me to update on AspNetCore and ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore. Okay, let's update them. Click on the Update button yielding the same message.

This is a brand new, I haven't added any code yet. Read these, no help

[Console app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45908613/package-restore-failed-rolling-back-package-changes-for-consoleapp1-while-ins), [Serilog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46169561/package-restore-failed-rolling-back-package-changes-serilog-aspnetcore), [MVC Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45784052/package-restore-failed-rolling-back-package-changes-for-myproject-in-vs-2017)

Comment: I recommend update your version of VS to latest stable release ie 15.6.4 at the moment and see if that solves it. Also why start a new project with asp.net core 1.x templates when 2.0 is out and 2.1 is coming soon?

Comment: @JoeAudette this is a company machine, hand-tired.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me your visual studio cannot access your package source. Check if the Nuget.Org  source has been added here Tools > nuget package manager > package manager settings > Package Sources if not, add source: https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json. If the package source already exists then just clear the cache. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8isK.png)